# How do I rename an <li> inside a <ul> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I need your help.

I couldn't find much reference material out there (if any) on the web, so I am turning to the help of the gurus and experts around this place.

How can I make a listbox, such that when an item is highlighted, and I click on the Rename button at the top, an input box with the li's current value will be placed in the same spot as the selected LI value and the user will have the option to rename the li item. The changes are then saved if the lisbox has lost its focus. Similar examples are Windows, when you click "rename" the list item becomes an input box for the user to rename the file. I'd like to mock the same functionality and apply it to a UL LI listbox.

For the sake of keeping things plain and simple, I am jQuery friendly.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('li').click(function(){

        $('li.active').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
    });



    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.active {
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
#colors {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="raname" onclick="renameLi()">
<ul id="colors">
    <li>red</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>purple</li>
</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A `ul` element is an "ordered list", not a listbox.

Comment: what do you mean by "rename"? do you mean "change the text of the item?" `$('this').text('my text')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/1/

Comment: Something like that, ya? http://jsfiddle.net/mb9khhzf/4/ -- give the user a way to cancel, which resets back to the original value. Also, double-click to edit is nice, and cancel active edit if a new element is selected. Save on lost focus is not enabled here in favor of an explicit "save" button. Enter to save, escape to cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution temporarily makes the li a input and when done replaces it back to a li

http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/1/

```
$('li').click(function(){

    $('li.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="change_me">');
    var val = $('#change_me').val();
    if ( val ) {
        $('#change_me').replaceWith('<li>' + val + '</li>');
    }
});
```

This incorporates the rename button:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/5/

This does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/6/

```
    $('li').click(function(){

    $('li.active').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    var li = $(this);
    $("#rename").click(function() {
        $(li).replaceWith('<input type="text" id="change_me">');
        $("#change_me").focus();
        setInterval(function(){
            var val = $("#change_me").val();
            if ( ! $("#change_me").is(":focus") ) {
                $('#change_me').replaceWith('<li>' + val + '</li>');
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Rather than clicking on the "Rename" button twice, is it possible to remove the input text box after the object loses it focus (ie the user clicks elsewhere besides the UL box)?

Comment: Absolutely flawless! I see that there are always more ways than one to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
var chosenValue;
var chosenIndex;
var newValue;

$('li').click(function(){

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings("li").removeClass('active');
    chosenValue = $(this).text();
    chosenIndex = $(this).index()+1;
    $(".rename").show().val(chosenValue);

});

$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
    newValue = $(".rename").val();
    $("li:nth-of-type("+chosenIndex+")").text(newValue);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4kg2612/4/)